# External script in jquery for calling all element ID

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have following piece of jquery script which is to post a data when clicking the element having id #bt-$id, the $id is a php variable which changes every time

```
 <script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){   
   $('#bt-$id').on('click', function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     $.ajax({ 
       type: 'post',  
       url: '$url', 
       data: $('form').serialize(), 
       success: function () {    
         alert('Success');
       } 
     }); 
   }); 
 }); 
 </script>
```

HTML Markup / DOM

```
 <li id='bt-10"> Link 1 </li>
 <li id='bt-11"> Link 1 </li>
 <li id='bt-12"> Link 1 </li>
```

I am asking can anybody suggest a better method to call this jquery code as an external script which covers all the IDs generated in DOM / HTML Markup instead of calling one by one ?

Comment: don't do it this way. have one single class on the elements you want handled this way, and embed the ID in a `data` attribute. then you only have to target ONE class, and get the id from the data. e.g. `$('.bt').on('click', function(e) { id = e.targetElement.attr('data-id'); }`

Comment: Thanks for the information. I got the point to certain extend what you suggested, can you please provide a detailed link on this about something how we embed the ID in data attribute ?

Comment: I agree with Marc mentioned. Define the elements you need click event with a generic class. However, if you still want the approach you are looking for w/o classes, just do this : $('[id]').on('click', function (e)

Comment: `<li data-id="10">Link 1</li>`, basically.

Comment: Yeah of-course, you taught me easy method. Thanks Marc :)

Comment: This can also be done with selectors, `$("li[id^='bt-']")` would select all the List Items with the ID beginning with 'bt-', Using the class makes it just easier, as Marc B points out. Making use of the Data attribute works fine too, but `.data("id")` is almost the same as `.attr("id")`, so take your pick unless you plan to store other data elements, take your pick. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Marc B I tried several times with the your coding and its not working. can you post the complete script added with my above coding

Comment: @Twisty: but at least data attributes don't have to be unique across the document. then you don't have to do string parsing to extract the actual id value from the DOM id string.

Comment: @MarcB: Very good point. Was only offering another method.

Comment: @Tom if you want more help, you're going to need to provide a bit more of your code. I would advise using something like jsfiddle.net to create an example.